# Select rows of ids that have a pattern without losing the other rows

Tags: r, grouping, unique, rows

I have the following data frame:

```
# Example:
_________________________
     | id  | day  | state
-------------------------

 [1,]    1    0    0
 [2,]    1    1    0
 [3,]    1    2    0
 [4,]    1    3    1
 [5,]    1    4    1
 [6,]    1    5    1
 [7,]    1    6    0
 [8,]    1    7    0
 [9,]    1    8    3
[10,]    2    0    0
[11,]    2    1    0
[12,]    2    2    0
[13,]    2    3    1
[14,]    2    4    1
[15,]    2    5    4
[16,]    3    0    0
[17,]    3    1    0
[18,]    3    2    1
[19,]    3    3    0
[20,]    3    4    4
[21,]    4    0    0
[22,]    4    1    1
[23,]    4    2    0
[24,]    4    3    0
[25,]    4    4    0
[26,]    4    5    1
[27,]    4    6    0
[28,]    4    7    3
[29,]    5    0    0
[30,]    5    1    1
[31,]    5    2    1
[32,]    5    3    0
[33,]    5    4    0
[34,]    5    5    4

# Code:
byRow <- TRUE

example.Matrix <- matrix(data = c(1, 0, 0,1, 1, 0,1, 2, 0,1, 3, 1,1, 4, 1,1, 5, 1,1, 6, 
0,1, 7, 0,1, 8, 3,2, 0, 0,2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1,2, 4, 1,2, 5, 4, 3, 0, 0,3,1, 0,3, 
2, 1,3, 3, 0,3, 4, 4,4, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 0,4, 3, 0,4, 4, 0,4, 5, 1,4, 6, 0,4, 7, 3,
5, 0, 0,5, 1, 1,5, 2, 1, 5, 3, 0, 5, 4, 0,5, 5, 4), byrow=TRUE,ncol=3)

example.df<-as.data.frame(example.Matrix)

colnames(example.df) <- c("id", "day", "states")
```

And I would like to do the following:

1) Create a data frame (or matrix) with ids which only have a unique value of 1 in states followed by anything in the next row except 1.  So for example that would look something like this:

```
# Expected output for first step:
_______________
|id|day|states|
----------------
3  | 2 |   1  |
3  | 3 |   0  |  
3  | 4 |   4  |  
----------------

# Example in code:
matrix.1<-matrix(c(3,2,1,3,3,0,3,4,4), byrow=TRUE,ncol=3)
df.1<-as.data.frame(matrix.1)
colnames(df.1) <- c("id", "day", "states")
```

Notice that in id 4 though there is a condition where the states goes from 1 to 0 they re-enter into 1 so id 4 should not be included in the new data frame/matrix.

```
# Should not be included in expected output for df.1:
_______________
|id|day|states|
----------------
4  | 1 |   1  | #* start 
4  | 2 |   0  | #* meets condition
4  | 3 |   0  | 
4  | 4 |   0  | 
4  | 5 |   0  | 
4  | 6 |   1  | #*reenters 1 - does not meet condition
4  | 7 |   0  | 
4  | 8 |   3  | 
---------------
```

2) Then once that data frame/matrix is constructed, I want to make a another data frame from the original (eg. with a for loop), but this time the condition is for individuals which have the following pattern in states: 1, followed by 1, followed by anything but 1. That would look something like this:

```
# Expected  output from second step:
_______________
|id|day|states|
----------------
2  | 3 |   1  |
2  | 4 |   1  |  
2  | 5 |   4  |  
5  | 1 |   1  |
5  | 2 |   1  |  
5  | 3 |   0  |  
5  | 4 |   0  |
5  | 5 |   4  |    
----------------
```

Likewise ids should not re-enter into 1 after meeting the condition

3) Afterwards I want to continue repeating this pattern, so the next one would be for individuals in states: 1, followed by 1, followed by 1, followed by anything but 1:

```
# Expected output from third step:
_______________
|id|day|states|
----------------
1  | 3 |   1  |
1  | 4 |   1  |  
1  | 5 |   1  |  
1  | 6 |   0  |
1  | 7 |   0  |  
1  | 8 |   3  |   
----------------
```

4) And then with that I am going to continue the pattern up to 29 consecutive 1s.

So in the end I hope to have 30 data frames/matrices with individuals matching the conditions above.

Comment: "id" 1 has 1,1,1,0 it has a sequence of three 1s it needs to be a unique 1 then any number afterwards that isn't 1. 

so 1,x... would be the pattern of interest in the first output
then 1,1,x... in the next output
then 1,1,1,x... in the next output
then 1,1,1,1,x... 

and so forth. Which is why "id" 1 does not work for the first output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a function to do this

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(data, n){
    ids <- data %>%
             mutate(stateslead = lead(states, default = last(states))) %>%
             group_by(grp = rleid(states == 1)) %>% 
             filter(n() == n, states == 1, stateslead != 1) %>%     
             group_by(id) %>%     
             filter(n() == 1) %>%
             pull(id)

    data %>%
       filter(id %in% ids) %>%
       group_by(id) %>% 
       filter(cumsum(states) > 0)



 }
```

-testing

```
f1(example.df, 1)
#  id day states
#1  3   2      1
#2  3   3      0
#3  3   4      4

f1(example.df, 2)
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
#     id   day states
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     2     3      1
#2     2     4      1
#3     2     5      4
#4     5     1      1
#5     5     2      1
#6     5     3      0
#7     5     4      0
#8     5     5      4

f1(example.df, 3)
#  id day states
#1  1   3      1
#2  1   4      1
#3  1   5      1
#4  1   6      0
#5  1   7      0
#6  1   8      3
```

Also, if we want to do this in one step, use `map` to loop over the 'n'

```
library(purrr)
out1 <- map(1:3, f1, data = example.df)
```

For the OP, `1:3` could be replaced with `1:29`.  The 'out1' is a `list` of `tibble/data.frame`s

Comment: Thank you akrun. While this seems to work with the example, it did not manage to do the same with the full data set. That said I'm going to try and see if the approach you used can shed light on a solution. Thank you very much for taking the time to come up with a solution also.

Comment: akrun, with your code I was able to get what I needed, I just needed to make a few adjustments to the data set I was using. Thank you so much for your help.